# Mongo $OR nested within $AND

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to construct a Mongo query that gets all documents meeting multiple $AND conditions as well as one or more $OR conditions.  My approach is below.

The $AND condition seems to be working as expected, but when I add the $OR, the results do not change. Any help is appreciated.

```
Collection.find({
    $and:[
      {lat: { $ne:""}},
      {lon: { $ne:""}},
      {type : "foo"},            
      {keywords:{ $regex : "bar", $options:"i" }},
      { $or:[
        {isOpen : "True"},
        {isOpen : "False"},              
        {price : { $gte: 0}},
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: You don't actually need to use `$and` here, but that looks fine otherwise. Can you update your question to include an example doc that's either not being returned or excluded as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a query where you only specify a comma delimited list of expressions as it implicitly does the AND operation for you. You can then include the or query in the list as follows:

```
var query = {
    lat: { $ne: ""},
    lon: { $ne:"" },
    type: "foo",            
    keywords: { $regex : "bar", $options:"i" },
    $or: [
        { isOpen: "True"},
        { isOpen: "False"},              
        { price: { $gte: 0}},
    ]
};

Collection.find(query);
```

You can refer the **[docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)**:

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

Comment: While true, isn't this functionally the same query that the OP is already using (unsuccessfully)?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, same functionality but only suggested the implicit implementation which may help the OP understand and adjust the query to return the desired results.

Comment: Hi Everyone - thanks for the help, I got this sorted in my $or: array was an empty json object {} that was catching all docs.  I was abbreviating my code in my Q, so you don't see it there.  Thanks again for the help, I did appreciate learning the $and was unnecessary.